# Ajax : empty param for POST request

Tags: ajax, symfony-3.3

I'm trying to count the redirections for a website,like when a user clicks on a link that refers to that website.
I'm getting the `url` through a request like below in my method :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/redirections")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function redirectingtoAction(Request $request) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query ="UPDATE urlproduit SET redirection = redirection + 1 WHERE url ='".$request->get('ur')."';";
        $statement = $em->getConnection()->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        return new Response($request->get('ur'));
    }
```

This is my twig :

```
    <div class="col-4 store-border-button ">
    <p data-url="{{url.url}}"  
    class="btn btn-primary wd-shop-btn pull-right flux"> See the offer </p> 
    </div>
```

and this is my ajax call code :

```
     $('.flux').click(function(){
            ur=$(this).data('url');
            console.log(url);
            $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../redirections",
    data : { param: 'ur', value: ur },
    success: function(data){
        //window.location.href=data;
        console.log(data);
    }});});
```

When checking the `_profiler` the ur is always empty like below :
[image: empty url param]

Comment: I don't quite get you. What's the difference between `ur` and `url`...?

Comment: ur is a variable used to stock the content of data-url="{{url.url}}" to avoid confusion.

Comment: So, what is returning `empty`... `ur` or `url`.. ?

Comment: the ur is empty.

Comment: OK. Edit your question. You stated that `url` is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was :

```
function hits(url){

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../redirects",
    data : {  url: url},
    success: function(data){
        window.location.href=data;

    }
    });
         };
```

and I modified the button code :

```
 <a href="{{url.url}}" target="_blank" onclick="hits('{{url.url}}');return false;" class="btn btn-primary wd-shop-btn pull-right" id="flux">
See offer </a>
```